# Transform a table with dynamic array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table on the left with several rows and columns as input.

I would like to obtain a table on the right by formulas.

Ideally, I'm looking for one dynamic array formula in J3, which takes D3:G3 and C4:C6 as arguments.

One dynamic array formula in J3 and another one in K3 will also be acceptable.

A solution with LAMBDA function would be second best (though you could still propose one), because not everyone is using beta channel.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `LET`:

`=LET(x,ROWS(C4:C6),y,COLUMNS(D3:G3),z,SEQUENCE(x*y)-1,CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(D3:G3,1+MOD(z,y)),INDEX(C4:C6,1+INT(z/y))))`

Comment: nice solution, thank you.