# Transform and filter a table with dynamic array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(* this question is one step further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872997/transform-a-table-with-dynamic-array-formulas). *)

I have the following table on the left with several rows and columns as input.

I would like to obtain a table on the right by formulas.

Ideally, I'm looking for one or more dynamic array formulas in J3, K3 and L3, which take D3:G3, C4:C6, and D4:G6 (or C3:G6) as arguments.

A solution with LAMBDA function would be second best (though you could still propose one), because not everyone is using beta channel.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You can use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH with the solution from your previous question. Tbh Power Query is a much better solution than formulas tho.

Comment: I prefer not to require intermediate rows/columns. These are solutions I prepare for someone else, so I really try to be exhaustive and find best solution.

Comment: [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) does not require intermediate rows/columns.

Comment: I think this question could be done without adding helper rows/columns, but the formula would be a little bit longer than my previous question. In this case, I prefer formula solutions to power query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=LET(x,ROWS(A2:A4),y,COLUMNS(B1:E1),z,SEQUENCE(x*y)-1,CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(B1:E1,1+MOD(z,y)),INDEX(A2:A4,1+INT(z/y)),INDEX(B2:E4,1+INT(z/y),1+MOD(z,y))))`

With credits to Jos Woolley for doing all of the pre-work.

and to filter out the empty values and rows without values you could use:

`=LET(x,ROWS(A2:A4),y,COLUMNS(B1:E1),z,SEQUENCE(x*y)-1,a,INDEX(B2:E4,1+INT(z/y),1+MOD(z,y)),b,CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(B1:E1,1+MOD(z,y)),INDEX(A2:A4,1+INT(z/y)),IF(a="","",a)),FILTER(b,INDEX(b,,3)<>""))`

[image]

Comment: actually, i need to fill out the rows where the third element is empty.

Comment: You can apply the `CHOOSE`-part to a variable, e.g. resultMatrix (like the ones before), then you can extend the formula with `FILTER(resultMatrix ;INDEX(resultMatrix;;3)=0)`

Comment: Please look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach this time:

`=LET(x,SMALL(IF(D4:G6<>"",10^5*SEQUENCE(ROWS(D4:G6))+SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(D4:G6))),SEQUENCE(COUNT(D4:G6))),y,INT(x/10^5),z,MOD(x,10^5),CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(D3:G3,z),INDEX(C4:C6,y),INDEX(D4:G6,y,z)))`

Most likely can be improved upon, however.

**Edit:** *Note*: in your example the non-blank entries in `D4:G6` are all numeric. If this is not necessarily always the case then replace `COUNT(D4:G6)` with `COUNTIF(D4:G6,"<>")` for a more generalised set-up.

Comment: that’s smart, i notice you like to use large numbers to do tricks, but that also makes the solution not work in extreme cases (e.g., when the table is very big).